# How to filter the array by multiple values from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays and want to filter the result from `data` array.

```
var data = [{"role":"Frontend", "languages": ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript"]},{"role":"Fullstack", "languages": ["JavaScript"]}]
var selectItem = ["CSS"];
```

Objects are added to selectItem[] once they `data` are selected from an UI.

I want to output by filtering from the `data` array against `selectItem`.

But the `selectItem` can have the values from both `role` and `languages`.

Like:

```
var selectItem = ["Frontend","CSS"];
```

I have tried to filter out the result:

```
  var users = this.myJson.filter(
        (el) =>
          this.selectItem.includes(el.role) ||
          el.languages.some((e1) => this.selectItem.indexOf(e1) >= 0)
      );
      console.log(users);
```

So, how can filter the `data` array with multiple keys? This query is filtering from the `languages` but not filtering the values from the `role`.

**Update**:

The query I tried was working but when the new item is added on the selectedItem like:

```
 var selectItem = ["Frontend","CSS", "HTML"];
```

It is still returning all the values because it contains the `CSS`.

So I want to filter the result if it contains all the tags that is `CSS` and `HTML` and `Frontend` in the `data`.

```js
var data = [
{"role":"Frontend", "languages": ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript"]},
{"role":"Fullstack", "languages": ["JavaScript"]},
{"role":"Frontend", "languages": ["CSS","JavaScript"]}

]

var selectItem = ["Frontend","CSS", "HTML"];

var users=data.filter(el => selectItem.length &&
   (selectItem.includes(el.role) ||
    el.languages.some(e1 => selectItem.includes(e1)) )
);
console.log(users);
```

My expected output is:

```
[{
  languages: ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript"],
  role: "Frontend"
}]
```

What is the best way of filtering with the multiple keys from array object?

Comment: so what is wrong with what you have? Is it an OR or does everything have to match in the search criteria?

Comment: It would be easier and more performant if the languages was transformed to a Set.

Comment: @epascarello I have modified my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to what I read from your first attempt, you are looking for those elements that fulfill **all** of the keyword-conditions and not just some of them. I changed my answer again to fulfill this requirement:

```js
var data = [
{"role":"Frontend", "languages": ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript"]},
{"role":"Fullstack", "languages": ["JavaScript"]},
{"role":"Frontend", "languages": ["CSS","JavaScript"]}];

var sel = ["Frontend","CSS","HTML"];

var users=data.filter(el => {
  if (sel&&sel.length){
//  let elall=[el.role].concat(el.languages);
    let elall=[el.role,...el.languages]; // <-- Aakash Bashyal <3
    return sel.every(se=>elall.includes(se))
  }
});
console.log(users);
```

In my code I create a local temporary array `elall` that contains *all* of the keywords in an element from both attributes (`role` and `languages`). Now, the `.every()` method on `sel` checks whether *every* keyword in `sel` is found in the `elall` array.

Comment: yeah, I found that is working when there are values, but how to filter with includes when the `selectItem` is empty or null? i had checked while there were not values so it was giving a error.

Comment: That is easy - see my modified answer - simply include a `selectItem.length && ...` into the `.filter()` function.

Comment: Yes, that seems to work! Your modified code filters out the second element, so the first and third elements are - rightfully - in the result set!

Comment: yes, it worked by the code you suggested, but what i wanted is: everything have to match in the search criteria.

Comment: I don't get it. Why should the second element match? Neither `Fullstack` nor `JavaScript` is in the `selectItem` array.

Comment: i don't need the second element and third element too.  because neither of them (second and thrid) have all three, ["Frontend","CSS", "HTML"].

Comment: ... changed my answer again - please check! ;-)

Comment: just a small question, what could be the differences in your choice of using concat over spread operator in the same solution?

Comment: Oh, I was just being "old-fashioned"! ;-) The spread operator works just as well and is more compact!

Answer (score 0):

This will give the desired result:

```
data.filter(d => 
    selectItem.includes(item => item == d.role) || 
    selectItem.some(item => d.languages.find(lang => lang == item))
);
```